# php fopen appending data but it is not showing

Tags: php, file, pdf, fopen

Hi I have two pdf files

```
$file1 = 'signed01.pdf';
$file2 = 'signed02.pdf';
```

Now, Signed01 is 1.8 MB and Signed02 is 426 KB the second file contains the signature in digital format that I want to append inside file1.

I have used

```
$file1 = 'signed196165991.pdf';
$file2 = 'signed1931217081.pdf';

$GlobalFileHandle = fopen($file1,'a'); 

$data = file_get_contents($file2);

fwrite($GlobalFileHandle, $data);

//file_put_contents($file1, $data, FILE_APPEND);

fclose($GlobalFileHandle);
```

Now this append the data to the file as I can see the file01 size is 2.3 MB now that is it is increased by 426 KB but when I open the file I can only see the data from file02 not the combined data for both files so it did append the data but I can not see it each time I run this file file01 size gets increased by 426KB but I can only see the data of file02.

Comment: PDFs are not text files, so you can’t simply paste the contents of one into the other. Instead, you need to use a library such as FPDF or MPDF. Also, if a file is signed, the signature is based on the file’s binary contents, so any changes, including appending pages, will invalidate the signature, and you’ll need to resign.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I need to replace 7-10 pages of the first pdf from all 4 pages of the second pdf is there any library in PHP that would help me to achieve that.